# JDK still pointing to 1.6 on Mac OSX 10.10.2

Tags: java, macos, java-6

So I have been trying to compile my code and I get the following error:

```
Information:Using javac 1.7.0_80-ea to compile java sources
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'DataRegistry'
Information:4/8/15, 9:48 AM - Compilation completed with 14 errors and 0 warnings in 2 sec
    /Users/jvy234/Documents/workspace/dataregistry/src/main/java/com/capitalone/hub/registry/controller/SandboxController.java
    Error:(169, 43) java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
      (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

I manually forced the CurrentSDK symlink to java 1.7:

```
6003088f811e:~ jvy234$ which java
/usr/bin/java
6003088f811e:~ jvy234$ ls -ltr /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Jan 21 09:52 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
6003088f811e:~ jvy234$ ls -ltr /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
total 64
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Jan 21 09:52 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Jan 21 09:52 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Jan 21 09:52 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Jan 21 09:52 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Jan 21 09:52 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Jan 21 09:52 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    1 Jan 21 09:52 Current -> A
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  238 Jan 21 09:52 A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   59 Apr  8 09:43 CurrentJDK -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/
```

When I go to my Preferences panel for Java I see Java 1.7_80 installed. What can I do to make it use JDK 1.7 ?

Comment: Have you tried `javac -source 7` for compiling ?

Comment: 6003088f811e:~ jvy234$ javac -source 7
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>

Comment: Could you please show how you are compiling ?

Comment: Sorry? I am not sure what you mean by how I am compiling?

Comment: How are you getting your first error message ?

Comment: Building my code in IntelliJ

Comment: IntelliJ still thinks its compiling for 1.6 and is passing the `-source 1.6` command-line option to javac.

Comment: I there anyway to change this easily? I set the default jdk to 1.7

Answer (score 0):

You can change the jdk used to compile your project `in File/Project Structure/SDKs/Java SDK` (see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/sdks-java.html)).

If you wish to change the compiler of your entire workspace, you can change the compiler used in `File/Settings/Build, Execution, Deployment/Compiler/Java Compiler` (see this [doc page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/compiler-java-compiler.html?search=java%20compiler#d1416600e126)).
If you still get the same error message, you can pass `-source 7` in the `javac` options.

Comment: Yes, I set the default to 1.7 and when I go down to additional command line parameters and add "-source 7" it does nothing.

Comment: @theMadKing Did you also test is the new part about changing jdk for the project ?

Comment: Yes changed the SDK as well.